# How streaming a large json in Suave?

Tags: json, f#, suave

I have a query that could return a large JSON in suave:

```
let queryCustomers(term, sorted:string) =
    use db = DbClient.openConn()
    let sort = sorted |> Customers.strToSorted

    CustomerDb.querySearch(db, term, sort) |>JsonUtils.toJson
```

The query return a Seq.

Now, I turn all the query in a single step to JSON, but wonder if is possible to speed up the whole operation and stream back the results:

```
let doReq route request action =
    path route >=> setCORSHeaders >=> request (fun r -> action(r) |> setJson)

doReq "/customers" request (fun r -> queryCustomers(r |> getTerm, r |> getSort))
```

Comment: Which part takes the time, the 'querySearch' or the JSON serialization and content delivery?  Put another way, does it take a long time to enumerate the first element in the sequence, or does it take a long time to enumerate from the second element of the sequence to the end?

Comment: Is return the whole JSON, after the query. I could even turn the query into an array and the effect is almost the same.